# Rails. Undefined method `scan' for :en:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I am trying to set up internationalization in my rails app. Use this article 
https://lingohub.com/blog/2013/08/internationalization-for-ruby-i18n-gem/

But I have error:

```
Failure/Error: http_accept_language.scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `scan' for :en:Symbol
```

My aplication controller:

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
end

private
def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
  request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
end
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby strings will respond to `#scan`, but not symbols. Try calling `#to_s` on the header value as below:

```
def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
  request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].to_s.scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
end
```